# Laravel mail con n archivos en attach

Tags: laravel, email

Uso Laravel 5.8. Tengo un mail definido con la clase mailable. Desde el controlador se le pasan los archivos que van a ir adjuntados al correo, en una matriz que está encapsulada en una colección, así:

```
$dataForMail = collect([
    'content' => [
        'encabezamiento' => 'Este es un correo de prueba.',
        'texto' => 'Este es un mensaje para probar los mailables.',
        'imagen' => 'images/img_02.jpg',
        'adjuntos' => [
            [
                'archivo' => 'pdfs/pdf_01.pdf',
                'enviarComo' => 'Primer adjunto PDF',
                'mime' => 'application/pdf',
            ],
            [
                'archivo' => 'pdfs/pdf_02.pdf',
                'enviarComo' => 'Segundo adjunto PDF',
                'mime' => 'application/pdf',
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

En la clase del mail tengo una variable para recibir los datos:

```
protected $mailData;
```

En el constructor asigno los datos a la variable:

```
public function __construct($receivedData)
{
    $this->mailData = $receivedData;
}
```

A la hora de poner los adjuntos, al objeto de la clase Mail le incorporo lo siguiente:

```
->attach(asset($this->mailData['content']['adjuntos'][0]['archivo']), [
    'as' => $this->mailData['content']['adjuntos'][0]['enviarComo'],
    'mime' => $this->mailData['content']['adjuntos'][0]['mime'],
])
->attach(asset($this->mailData['content']['adjuntos'][1]['archivo']), [
    'as' => $this->mailData['content']['adjuntos'][1]['enviarComo'],
    'mime' => $this->mailData['content']['adjuntos'][1]['mime'],
])
```

Y sí. Esto funciona perfectamente. Lo he probado con Mailtrap, y los correos se envían, con sus adjuntos, que llegan con su nombre... Todo sale perfecto.

El problema es que sé que pasan dos adjuntos, y encadeno dos métodos `attach()`. La cuestión es ¿Cómo hacerlo cuando pase un número indefinido de archivos? evidentemente, no puedo meter un bucle en la definición del objeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, en la misma definición del objeto no puedes insertar instrucciones para crear un bucle. Sin embargo, en un bucle si puedes modificar el objeto.
Seguramente tú tienes algo como esto en tu mailable:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view($this->mailData['vista'])
    .... /más métodos
    ->attach(asset($this->mailData['content']['adjuntos'][0]['archivo']), [
                    'as' => $this->mailData['content']['adjuntos'][0]['enviarComo'],
                    'mime' => $this->mailData['content']['adjuntos'][0]['mime'],
                ])    
    ->attach(asset($this->mailData['content']['adjuntos'][1]['archivo']), [
                    'as' => $this->mailData['content']['adjuntos'][1]['enviarComo'],
                    'mime' => $this->mailData['content']['adjuntos'][1]['mime'],
                ]);    
}
```

Prueba a crear primero el objeto en una variable, luego añadirle los attached con un bucle, y luego retornarlo. Me explicaré mejor con un ejemplo:

```
public function build()
{
    $correo = $this->view($this->mailData['vista'])
    .... /más métodos
    ;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->mailData['content']['adjuntos']); $i ++) {
        $correo->attach(asset($this->mailData['content']['adjuntos'][$i]['archivo']), [
                    'as' => $this->mailData['content']['adjuntos'][$i]['enviarComo'],
                    'mime' => $this->mailData['content']['adjuntos'][$i]['mime'],
                ]);
    }

    return $correo;
}
```

De este modo, tienes el mail en memoria, le pasas el `attach()` con cada uno de los adjuntos que haya, sean los que sean, y finalmente, lo retornas para ser enviado.

Comment: Guau. Funciona y es genial